# Finding "most frequently intersected area"?

Tags: intersection, geopandas

I have a geodataframe that contains geometries of droughted area for several years. To identify consistently droughted areas, I want to find areas that are droughted for the largest number of years.

In the image below, the 3 shapes represent droughted area outlines over 3 separate years. I want to end up with a geodataframe (or list of shapely polygons) with a count of the number of overlaps. So area A = 2, B = 3, and C = 2. I can then symbolize by color to show areas that are consistently droughted.

[image]

I've tried to get intersected areas only then perform a spatial join, but I can't figure out how to perform a "count" using GeoPandas. [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190648/summing-attribute-values-for-areas-where-multiple-polgons-overlap-using-arcgis-d) seems close to what I want, but I wasn't able to translate it to Python (not using ArcPy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import unary_union, polygonize

xcoords = [1,3,2,0] 
ycoords = [1,2,4,3]

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x=xcoords, y=ycoords))
df.geometry = df.geometry.buffer(2)
df.plot(color="red", edgecolor="black", alpha=0.3, figsize=(10,10))
```

Four circles that overlap 1-4 times:

[image]

```
#Create a dataframe of non-overlapping polygons
unioned = unary_union(df.boundary) #Union all boundaries to create a multilinestring of them all.
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=list(polygonize(list(unioned.geoms))))
df2.plot(color="red", edgecolor="black", alpha=0.3, figsize=(10,10))
```

[image]

```
#Intersect df and df2. Where df overlaps itself, the geometries in intersection output will be duplicated as
#  many times as it intersects.
intersected = gpd.overlay(df1=df, df2=df2, how="intersection", keep_geom_type=True)

#Count number of duplicate geometries. Although the wont be exactly the same, their vertices might be in
#  different order. So we consider polygons with the same centroid coordinates and area as duplicates.
intersected["centroid_and_area"] = intersected.apply(
    lambda x: 
    f"{round(x.geometry.centroid.x, 2)}, {round(x.geometry.centroid.y, 2)}, {round(x.geometry.area, 2)}", axis=1)

intersected["n_overlaps"] = intersected.groupby("centroid_and_area").transform("count")
intersected = intersected.drop_duplicates(subset="centroid_and_area")
intersected.plot(column="n_overlaps", figsize=(10,10), cmap="cool", legend=True, categorical=True)
```

[image]

```
#To find the polygon(s) with the most overlaps:
intersected.loc[intersected.n_overlaps == intersected.n_overlaps.max()]
                                             geometry  ... n_overlaps
17  POLYGON ((1.39018 2.96157, 1.58057 2.91388, 1....  ...          4

[1 rows x 3 columns]
```